# First stream freezes after seccond connection opens?

Tags: javascript, canvas, stream, data-uri

I'm constructing an application that allows multiple devices to stream their webcam, through the browser, to another device. Each streaming device takes a `DataURL` image from the webcam and sends it over `WebSocket` to a server, which will then distribute the array of images to viewers. The viewer will parse the message and display each image on its own individual `<canvas>`.

It works fine when one user is streaming, but when a second device begins to stream, the first one freezes. It appears the last image in the array is the only one to actually be rendered.

I've been reviewing this code for several hours and can't understand what I'm missing here.

```js
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://my_server:8443");


socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
  //parse the incoming message into a usable array
  msg = JSON.parse(msg.data);

  var div = document.getElementById("streams");
  
  //for every incoming stream
  for (var i in msg) {
    //create a new Image, then render it onto a canvas element.
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      //if there isn't a canvas element to render it onto already, create one (for when a stream is created)
      if (document.getElementById(i) == null) {
        var c = document.createElement("canvas");
        c.width = img.width;
        c.height = img.height;
        c.setAttribute("id", i);
        div.appendChild(c);
      }
      //draw the image onto the canvas
      var canvas = document.getElementById(i);
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
    //set the Data URL as the image's SRC
    img.src = msg[i];
  }
}
```

I originally just added `<img>` elements to the `<div>`, but it ended up taking too long to load, creating short flashes in between each frame.

What's wrong with my code? It seems to freeze all active streams except for the one most recently started (last in the array).